# YouTube player not working without continuous mouse movement over it

Tags: flash, internet-explorer-8

What can be the cause of the YouTube player not working (playing, buffering, firing api events) if I don't continuously move the cursor over the player?

Comment: You tagged this question as `internet-explorer-8`. Does that mean you're not seeing the problem in other browsers?

Comment: No problems with mac browsers (chrome, safari, opera, firefox), no problems with opera and firefox on windows, no problems with ie6 and ie7. Also problems doesn't disappear if I use compatibility mode.

Answer (score 1):

Try updating/reinstalling the flash player. That might fix your problem.

Comment: Worst case you can try an IE8 repair/reinstall, if it's just IE8.